# Why no_proxy must be specified for CURL to work in this scenario?

Tags: docker, nginx, curl, proxy, parse-server

Inside my virtual machine, I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:1.23.1-alpine"
    container_name: parse-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  mongo-0:
    image: "mongo:5.0.6"
    container_name: parse-mongo-0
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-0/data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-0/config:/data/config

  server-0:
    image: "parseplatform/parse-server:5.2.4"
    container_name: parse-server-0
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - ./server-0/config-vol/configuration.json:/parse-server/config/configuration.json
    command: "/parse-server/config/configuration.json"
```

The `configuration.json` file specified for `server-0` is as follows:

```
{
  "appId": "APPLICATION_ID_00",
  "masterKey": "MASTER_KEY_00",
  "readOnlyMasterKey": "only",
  "databaseURI": "mongodb://mongo-0/test"
}
```

After using `docker compose up`, I execute the following command from the VM:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID_00" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"score":1000,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

The output is:

```
{"objectId":"yeHHiu01IV","createdAt":"2022-08-25T02:36:06.054Z"}
```

I use the following command to get inside the `nginx` container:

```
docker exec -it parse-nginx sh
```

Pinging `parse-server-0` shows that it does resolve into a proper IP address.  I then run the modified version of the `curl` command above changing `localhost` with that host name:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID_00" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"score":1000,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' http://parse-server-0:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

It gives me a 504 error like this:

```
...
        <title>504 DNS look up failed</title>
    </head>
    <body><div class="message-container">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <h1>504 DNS look up failed</h1>
    <p>The webserver reported that an error occurred while trying to access the website. Please return to the previous page.</p>
...
```

However if I use `no_proxy` as follows, it works:

```
no_proxy="parse-server-0" curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID_00" -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: MASTER_KEY_00" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"score":1000,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' http://parse-server-0:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

The output is again something like this:

```
{"objectId":"ICTZrQQ305","createdAt":"2022-08-25T02:18:11.565Z"}
```

I am very perplexed by this.  Clearly, `parse-server-0` is reachable with ping.  How can it then throws a 504 error without using `no_proxy`?  The `parse-nginx` container is using default settings and configuration.  I do not set up any proxy.  I am using it to test the `curl` command from another container to `parse-mongo-0`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

The contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options edns0 trust-ad ndots:0
```

Running `echo $HTTP_PROXY` inside `parse-nginx` returns:

```
http://10.10.10.10:8080
```

This value is null inside the VM.

Comment: What is the value of **http_proxy** in `parse-nginx` container? Also, what are the values in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @RahulSharma, I have added the requested info.

Comment: Please check the value of `echo $http_proxy` too. Please note the downcase here. If this value is set, that means `curl` is configured to use the proxy. And specifying `no_proxy` tells it to ignore the `http_proxy` env var. But I'm not sure about why you'd get 504. This most probably would have to do with the kind of server at `10.10.10.10`.

Comment: Also please try and unset `$http_proxy` and `$HTTP_PROXY` and see if the curl command works without `no_proxy`.

Comment: Yep!  The culprit is the `~/.docker/config.json` file in the VM, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy server doesn't appear to be running in this docker network. So when the request goes to that proxy server, it will not query the docker DNS on this network to resolve the other container names.

If your application isn't making requests outside of the docker network, you can remove the proxy settings. Otherwise, you'll want to set `no_proxy` for the other docker containers you will be accessing.

Comment: Thanks!  I narrowed down the search and fixed the issue with the clue from `HTTP_PROXY`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of `echo $http_proxy`. Please note the downcase here. If this value is set, that means curl is configured to use the proxy. You're getting 504 while DNS resolution most probably because your `parse-nginx` container isn't able to reach the ip `10.10.10.10`. And specifying `no_proxy` tells it to ignore the http_proxy env var (overriding it) and make the request without any proxy.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out.  Your answer helps narrowing down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inside my VM, this is the contents of the `~/.docker/config.json` file:

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://10.10.10.10:8080",
     "httpsProxy": "http://10.10.10.10:8080"
   }
 }
}
```

This was implemented a while back as an ad hoc fix for some network issues.  A security certificate was later implemented.  I completely forgot about the fix.  Clearing the `~/.docker/config.json` file, and redoing `docker compose up` fixes the issue.  I no longer need `no_proxy` to make `curl` works.  Everything is as it should be now.  Thank you so much for all the help.